# Why the condition for empty input is not working?

Tags: reactjs

What Im trying to do, is to handle the input from on a handle function. The first condition is for special characters like: ?/., etc. And the second condition is for empty input, in this case, when the user doesn't fill the name form and leave it empty. The action in this code is saving the client to the database.

```
function onChangeinput(event){
    updateState({ ...formState, [event.target.name]: event.target.value});
    if (event.target.name == "name"){
      setNamefield(event.target.value)

      const regex = /[a-zA-Z0-9_-]/; //for special characters 
      if (regex.test(event.target.value) === false) {
        setErrorMessageName("Max. length: 128 characters. May include numbers, letters");
        setDisableButton(true); 
      }
      else if(event.target.value > 0) {
        setDisableButton(true);
        setErrorMessageName("Input is empty...");
      }
    }
  }
```

To check if in the input name form is empty, I have put a condition that `if(event.target.value > 0)`: make the statement.
But in this case the condition doesn't work.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Use `if(event.target.value.length === 0)`

Answer (score 0):

if the **event.target.value** is an array

you can use `if(event.target.value?.length === 0)`

if is an object `if(!event.target.value)`

Answer (score 0):

```
else if(event.target.value > 0)
{
    setDisableButton(true);
    setErrorMessageName("Input is empty...");
}
```

kicks in when the `event.target.value` is greater than 0 .
To check if the value is empty it should be :

```
else if(event.target.value <= 0)
{
    setDisableButton(true);
    setErrorMessageName("Input is empty...");
}
```

this will kick in when `event.target.value` is smaller or equal to zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onChange(event){
    event.persist();
    updateFormState({ ...formState, [event.target.name]: event.target.value});
    if (event.target.name == "llname"){
      setLlnamefield(event.target.value)
      setErrorMessageLlname("")

      const regex = /[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,128}/; //for special characters 
      if (regex.test(event.target.value) === false) {
        setErrorMessageName("Max. length: 128 characters. May include numbers, letters, underscore (_), and hyphens (-).");
        setDisableButton(true); 
      }
      else if(event.target.value.trim().split(" ").join().trim().length<=0){
        setDisableButton(true);
        setErrorMessageName("Input is empty...");
      }
    }
  }
```

```js
const arr = " f    ";
console.log(arr.trim().split(" ").join().trim().length<=0)
```

Comment: I did your logic, but when I type a letter in the input it says: "Input is empty...", which I want the opposite

Comment: Hey , can you tell me what did you enter in the input ?

Comment: I have added a js code ... which just checks that specific code

Comment: I entered a name

Comment: Correct me if  I am wrong, but ur snippet returns true, and the ```arr``` is not empty, I wanted to return true when the ```arr``` is empty in ur case

Comment: Ohh , then just add only one exclamation mark .

Comment: At your condition?

Comment: It should work now

Comment: Does it work ? Please inform me once you test it from your side

Comment: When I type a name, and I delete it with backspace, the condition works. Im want  if the user doesn't put a name at all.